# Move focus when input number maxlength is reached

Tags: forms, input, numbers, setfocus

I have a form, were user have to input their birth date:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="day" class="sr-only">[[%day]]</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="31" maxlength="2" class="form-control input-lg name="day" value="[[+day]]" placeholder="day">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="day" class="sr-only">[[%day]]</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="31" maxlength="2" class="form-control input-lg name="day" value="[[+month]]" placeholder="month">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="day" class="sr-only">[[%day]]</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="31" maxlength="4" class="form-control input-lg name="day" value="[[+year]]" placeholder="year">
</div>
```

I understand, that `type="number"` does not support the attribute `maxlength`.

I have to make like this:

When customer inputs 2 digits into `day`, the next input field becomes automatically focused and so on... Only numbers are allowed for input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
(You need to import jquery lib.)

```
<input type="number" id="date">
<input type="number" id="date">

<script>
  txt_day=$("#day");
  txt_year=$("#year");
  txt_day.change(function(){
     if(tt_day.val().length;
     txt_year.focus();
  }

</script>
```